# Get a user presence Microsoft Graph Api using Graph SDK 5.17.0 C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

i am working with graph API for teams and new to the graph API. I need to get user presence. The API is working fine with [graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) by using the following endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/presence

I am using this end point in my windows application (C# .net Core). I am creating class library and added Graph SDK 5.17.0 .

I have given the delegated Permission Presence.Read and Presence.Read.All from organization account.

1. I am trying with client secret by using tenantId, clientId, clientSecret
   It throws an error like 'Forbidden'
2. I am trying with the following

   ```
    Using Azure.Identity;
    Using Microsoft.Graph;
   ```

The code as follows

```
var tenantId = "MytenantId";
var clientId = "MyclientId";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new UsernamePasswordCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

//var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var scopes = new[] { "Presence.Read" };
var userName = "my@mail.com";
var password = "Password1!";

var userNamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(
    userName, password, tenantId, clientId, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(userNamePasswordCredential, scopes);

var mypresence = await graphClient.Users["userid"].Presence.GetAsync();
var mypresence1 = await graphClient.Users["email"].Presence.GetAsync();
var mypresence2 = await graphClient.Me.Presence.GetAsync();
```

It's not returning the presence

Comment: When using the client secret and id to initialize client you need Application permission. In that case you have to use `client. Users[username].Presence.GetAsync()`. And what get you returned in your code example in `mypresence`?

Comment: @Oliver It's a delegate permission, can we access it by using client secret

Comment: What does it mean that "it's not returning the presence"? Does it throw any exception? I would add Presence.Read.All to scopes => var scopes = new[] { "Presence.Read", "Presence.Read.All" };

Comment: Sorry, a _delegate permission_ means, you connect with a specific user to graph and act as this specific user (e.g. /me points to this user). An application permission means you act in the name of the application by connecting via client secret and allows access to everything you are allowed to by the given _applicaton permissions_.

Comment: it's not a good idea to use ROPC flow to pass the authentication in you web app. Using delegated api permission means you should let your users sign in first to pass the authentication and then call the api on behalf of the users themselves. Here's a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/README.md) for web app integrating Azure AD and calling graph api with delegated permission.

Comment: if you don't want the users to sign in first, you should use application api permission.

Comment: @TinyWang Presence doesn't contains app permission. And i need to use it in Windows application